# Apply a function to an argument inside a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I apply a function to an argument of a SUMIF or COUNTIF formula?
For example:

```
=SUMIF(YEAR(B1:B10),"2017", A1:A10)
```

Where `B1:B10` contains an array of dates. For example:

```
1   A    B          
2   200  01/01/2017
3   300  01/01/2017
4   420  01/01/2016
5   250  01/01/2016
```

When I try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A*(YEAR(B:B)=2017))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5*(YEAR(B1:B5)=2017))
```

I get `#REF!` however if I define the ranges like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5*(YEAR(B2:B5)=2017))
```

I get the result I expect.

Comment: You mean you want a `map` over the array and sum the results?

Comment: One way might be to create another range of cells that have `=YEAR(B1)` to `=YEAR(B10)` and use those in the `SUMIF()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT` with arrays. Multiplying by a boolean array converts it to `0 or 1` array:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A10*(YEAR(B1:B10)=2017))
```

p.s.: this is a valid normal formula, no need for `CSE`.

On the other hand, `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` want their range arguments to be pure ranges, not arrays.

---

So it appears that your data is heterogeneous and some cells are not numbers or not dates. To deal with this, try this **array formula**:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5), A1:A5, 0)*(YEAR(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B5),B1:B5,0))=2017))
Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Comment: I am getting yelled at over on SuperUser because I used `CSE` and not `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`: https://superuser.com/questions/1212430/highlight-max-absolute-value-in-a-row-of-data/1212432?noredirect=1#comment1769489_1212432

Comment: As you can see I have not and will not change it.

Comment: @capm to do the COUNT just replace the `A1:A10*` with `--` and it will do the count.

Comment: @ScottCraner haha, it's the first time I use the abbreviated `CSE`, good that you warned me. Besides, excellent information for the COUNT case and beautiful alternative :)

Comment: Will I be able to use `YEAR(INDEX(dbProg,,13))=2017` with the SUMPRODUCT? On other sheets the `SUMPRODUCT` function works fine for this task, but when I try to map over the array with the `YEAR` function it results in error. (`dbProg` is a dynamically named range on another sheet).

Comment: I found out the problem, it doesn't have to do with the sheets or the `INDEX` to reference the range. It has to do with the range, if I use `L:L` to define the range, I get `#REF` error, the range must have only the values to be mapped by the function, not even the headers of the range must be included.

Comment: @capm I 'm sorry I can't follow you. I ecpect `#N/A` when the arrays in the formula are not of same size. #REF is a very specific meaning that the referenced range doesn't even exist or was deleted.

Comment: @capm Try the array formula I added at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you really like the SUMIF then you will need to use SUMIFS and bracket the date:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">=1/1/2017",B:B,"<=12/31/2017")
```

You can do the same with COUNTIFS.

Comment: Actually I wanted to apply functions to the arguments, like `YEAR` or `TEXT`. Both @A.S.H and @Harsha Vardhan answers work fine but have some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER ( CSE )

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(B7:B10,"YYYY")="2017")*A1:A10)
```

Comment: I get a formula error when the ranges are dynamically named and they are called with `INDEX` function, for example:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(INDEX(dbProg,,4), "YYYY")=A5))*INDEX(dbProg,,13))`
Where: `dbProg` is the name of a range dynamically named in the active workbook but the data is located in other spreadsheet, `A5` is the cell that contains the year and `4` and `13` are the columns where the dates and the amounts are.

Comment: You might have to use INDIRECT(INDEX())

Comment: I found out the error, it doesnt have to do with the `INDIRECT` reference for the range. The range must have only the values to be analyzed by the function `TEXT` or else I get `#REF`, for example I can't use `B:B` for the range. Also, if I want the `2007` to be a condition in another cell like `--TEXT(B7:B10, "YYYY")=A6` I get `0`.